# Using X509_SIG with earlier openssl

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography

I have code using X509_SIG structures that do not work not with OpenSSL 1.1.1 because the structure is now opaque. The purpose of the code consists of getting a PKCS#1 content from a X509_SIG. But with the OpenSSL change I cannot build the X509_SIG buffer.

My code is similar than OpenSSL encode_pkcs1() function from  crypto\rsa\rsa_sign.c [https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c] :

```
X509_SIG sig;
X509_ALGOR algor;
ASN1_TYPE parameter;
ASN1_OCTET_STRING digest;
uint8_t *der = NULL;
int len;

sig.algor = &algor;
sig.algor->algorithm = OBJ_nid2obj(type);
parameter.type = V_ASN1_NULL;
parameter.value.ptr = NULL;
sig.algor->parameter = &parameter;

sig.digest = &digest;
sig.digest->data = (unsigned char *)m;
sig.digest->length = m_len;

len = i2d_X509_SIG(&sig, &der);
```

I have changed a few things like using X509_SIG * instead of X509_SIG. I made other changes and now it is compiling. But it will not work because X509_SIG was not allocated and is not initialized. type, m and m_len are arguments to the function.

Is there a way for simply generating a DER buffer with the digest structure (ASN1_OCTET_STRING) and the algorithm structure (X509_ALGOR and ASN1_TYPE) ?

I may hardcode the generation. But, I am looking for a simple API that I did not find.

Answer (score 1):

This is a area that is not really well documented.

There is functions you can all to allocation and free sigs:

- X509_SIG_new
- X509_SIG_free

You can read/write SIG to/from ASN1 format using

- d2i_PKCS8_bio / _fp
- i2d_PKCS8_bio / _fp

And most likely what you are after, you can encrypt and decrypt to/from a SIG from a PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO structure.

```
X509_SIG *PKCS8_encrypt(int pbe_nid, const EVP_CIPHER *cipher,
                        const char *pass, int passlen,
                        unsigned char *salt, int saltlen, int iter,
                        PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *p8inf);

PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *PKCS8_decrypt(const X509_SIG *p8, const char *pass,
                                   int passlen);
```

PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO APIS:

```
PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO_new
PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO_free
EVP_PKEY *EVP_PKCS82PKEY(const PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *p8);
PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *EVP_PKEY2PKCS8(EVP_PKEY *pkey);
int PKCS8_pkey_set0(PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *priv, ASN1_OBJECT *aobj,
                    int version, int ptype, void *pval,
                    unsigned char *penc, int penclen);
int PKCS8_pkey_get0(const ASN1_OBJECT **ppkalg,
                    const unsigned char **pk, int *ppklen,
                    const X509_ALGOR **pa, const PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *p8);

const STACK_OF(X509_ATTRIBUTE) *
PKCS8_pkey_get0_attrs(const PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *p8);
int PKCS8_pkey_add1_attr_by_NID(PKCS8_PRIV_KEY_INFO *p8, int nid, int type,
                                const unsigned char *bytes, int len);
```

I *think* this is enough for you to do what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found that using these APIs would complicate unnecessarily the code. So, I rewrite the function and simplify the process.